# Installing OPC/UA client on Linux

Tags: python, linux, qt

I have a [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) 3, and I am trying to connect to OPC UA Server. For this I am referring to [OPCUA-Client GUI](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-client-gui). I have installed it using `sudo pip install opcua-client`, but it's showing an error of `pyqt5.qtcore`.

I have installed qt by using `sudo apt-get install qt5-default pyqt5-dev pyqt5-dev-tools`. But still it's showing the below error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/bin/opcua-client", line 7, in <module>
    from uaclient.mainwindow import main   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uaclient/mainwindow.py", line 9, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QTimer, Qt, QObject, QSettings, QModelIndex, QMimeData, QCoreApplication ImportError: No module named PyQt5.QtCore`
```

How do I install PyQt5.Qtcore in order to run `opcua-client`?

Comment: execute:  `sudo apt-get install python-pyqt5`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thankyou. That command worked. But now when I am running `opcua-client` it shows error `ImportError: No module named uaclient`

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling that package?

Comment: @eyllanesc may be thats an issue with the python version I am using. I am using 2.7 and it works with python3 I guess as described [here](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-client-gui/issues/16) So I am trying with python3

Comment: then execute `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks. I am now able to run `opcua-client` on my pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `OPCUA-Client` is not compatible with Python2.7, so I had to install it using Python3.

```
sudo pip3 install cryptography

sudo pip3 install opcua-client

sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

Thanks to @eyllanesc